# Distant update of a linux box

Tags: linux, update

I have a bunch of home-made Linux boxes (made with buildroot) and I would like them to get auto-updated throught an internet fixed IP of my ubuntu server.

I would like to update the kernel and also some files or directories etc.

I began my own ssh script that would list the files of a /home/update/ on the box from the server and if necessary upload the latest one and then run a script in it that would do every changes but...

I don't think it is the right way and I would like to know if there are some short easy path to do that.

Thanks :)

Comment: I'd like busybox to come with somthing like that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can package all your files as Debian packages and all the systems are identical, [you could create a custom repository](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42862) on your server containing the packages that these system needs, then they would just need to `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` on a regular basis.  You'll want to be sure you test this repository on a local copy of the system before you end up with "distant" computers that have no ssh server or are otherwise broken.

Otherwise, you'll probably need to use something like [Puppet](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/526) (continued [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/528)) or [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) to manage all of these systems and the changes to them.

Answer (score 1):

"rsync" is a good command for this. It automatically uses SSH to connect and compares remote files to local to determine which need to be updated.

There are lots of options, so you will want to read the documentation at http://rsync.samba.org/documentation.html

It's a great way to keep a local and remote directory or file up to date.

If you're updating installed programs, kernels, etc, you should consider using "yum update" (fedora / redhat) or "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade" (ubuntu /debian). For a custom-built kernel or apps, you will likely need to do your own custom update script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here but, have you looked into `yum update` or similar command for ubuntu?
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=11103

Comment: @3molo Are you having trouble reading through entire sentence and looking through the link?